# Item appearing below current page content, want it to be floating window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am using React.
I have 2 class components:

1. MyPage
2. NewComponent  (path: /api/pages/components/new)

Here is my NewComponent class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';


class NewComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    

    render(){
        return(
              <Modal.Dialog>
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>New Component</Modal.Title>
                         </Modal.Header>
                </Modal.Dialog>

        );
    }
}

export default NewComponent;
```

Here is my Page class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


class MyPage extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    

    render(){
        return(
        
            {/**   some code .... */}
            
              <div className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0">
                <Router>

                    <NavLink to={Routes.NewComponentForm.path}>
                        <Button id="addComponent" className="btn btn-dark rounded-circle btn-lg" >+</Button>
                         <Route path="/api/pages/components/new" component={NewComponentForm}/>
                    </NavLink>
                </Router>
               </div>
        );
    }
    
}

export default MyPage;
```

My Question:

The items of the NewComponent class are rendered on the same page below the items of the MyPage class.

What I want is to have the Modal component (NewComponent class) to be a floating window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought was that you hadn't [imported the the stylesheet](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets) from `react-bootstrap` into your project.

But it's actually a problem with your `react-router-dom` setup.

You want to have **one** `Router` component at the outermost level of your app.  You can have multiple blocks of `Route`s in the same `Router`.  Unless you are doing something complex with nested routes you probably only have one set of `Route` components which go inside a `Switch` statement in your `App`.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={Routes.NewComponentForm.path} component={NewComponentForm} />
        <Route component={MyPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

in `MyPage`

```
return(
  {/**   some code .... */}
  <div className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0">
    <NavLink to={Routes.NewComponentForm.path}>
      <Button id="addComponent" className="btn btn-dark rounded-circle btn-lg" >+</Button>
    </NavLink>
  </div>
);
```

I'm confused about the relationship between `NewComponent` and `NewComponentForm`.  Here I am assuming that the route with the form renders the modal.